# Updating variables in for loop with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Basically the code is supposed to run this function for 10 iterations: F(n) = 5 * F(n-1) - 4 * F(n-2) where F(0)=2 and F(1)=5. F(2) should be 17 and F(3) should be 65.
Problem is, when I'm running this, the variables don't seem to update so I'm stuck with it repeating with first three variables correctly (2, 5, and 17) and then 17 as well for the rest of the results. (Screenshot of the exact results below the code). Where did I go wrong?

```
declare
justn int;
nminusone int;
nminustwo int;
begin
--action;
nminusone := 5;
nminustwo := 2;
dbms_output.put_line('F(0) is: ' || nminustwo);
dbms_output.put_line('F(1) is: ' || nminusone);
for i in 2..10 loop
 justn := 5*nminusone-4*nminustwo;
 nminusone := justn;
 nminustwo := nminusone;
 dbms_output.put_line('F(' || i || ') is: ' || justn);
end loop;
end;
```

[Screenshot of my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMqs3.png)

Comment: You are not using a function; please look at whether your assignment requires you to create a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of assignments. Current order makes `nminustwo` and `nminusone` equal.

```
 ..
 nminustwo := nminusone;
 nminusone := justn;
 ..
```